# Why Currency.defaultFractionDigits() for IDR is 0 for android?

Tags: java, android, localization, currency

For Indonesian currency (IDR), `defaultFractionDigits()` gives me `0` in Android app.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("in", "ID");
Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
Log.d("TEST",String.format(locale, "Currency - %s ( %s )  Decimal - %s ",
        currency.getSymbol(locale),
        currency.getSymbol(),
        currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()));
```

> D/TEST: Currency - Rp ( IDR )  Decimal - 0

Same gives me `2` when I'm testing it in my eclipse (also in [RexTester](http://rextester.com/VLHWE30432))

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("in","ID"));
Currency c = Currency.getInstance("IDR");
System.out.println("Symbol: " + c.getSymbol());
System.out.println("Default fractional digits: " + c.getDefaultFractionDigits());
```

> Symbol: Rp
>
> Default fractional digits: 2

Documentation of both [Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html) & [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) states that it's **ISO 4217** (ISO 4217:2015 lists the IDR with two-digit decimal points)

Why it's `0` for Android App?

Comment: Your Android code uses "in" locale, not "id"

Comment: Oops, mistake while posting. both are "in". updated the question now

Comment: Not proper described

Comment: maybe it's connected with that according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_rupiah Subunit(sen) is obsolete
ISO 4217 has versions f.e most recent is ISO 4217:2015
(https://www.iso.org/iso-4217-currency-codes.html), and maybe there are different versions on Android and other system

Comment: @Wrobel Even if the sen is de facto obsolete in cash payments, ISO 4217:2015 still lists the Indonesian rupiah as having a subunit with a two digit fraction. It is still used in accounting and e.g. bank transfers though.

Answer (score 2):

I ran this jUnit code in my Android Studio 3.0.1 with JRE 1.8.0_152:

```
@Test
public void defaultFractionDigits_isCorrect() throws Exception {
    Locale locale = new Locale("in", "ID");
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    assertEquals(2, currency.getDefaultFractionDigits());
}

@Test
public void defaultFractionDigits2_isCorrect() throws Exception {
    Locale locale = new Locale("in", "ID");
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    assertEquals("Currency - Rp ( IDR )  Decimal - 2 ",
            String.format(locale, "Currency - %s ( %s )  Decimal - %s ",
            currency.getSymbol(locale),
            currency.getSymbol(),
            currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()));
}
```

And both tests passed. I then ran this test to check for the result that you are getting:

```
@Test
public void defaultFractionDigits3_isCorrect() throws Exception {
    Locale locale = new Locale("in", "ID");
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    assertEquals("Currency - Rp ( IDR )  Decimal - 0 ",
            String.format(locale, "Currency - %s ( %s )  Decimal - %s ",
            currency.getSymbol(locale),
            currency.getSymbol(),
            currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()));
}
```

And the test failed with:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Currency - Rp ( IDR )  Decimal - 0 
Actual   :Currency - Rp ( IDR )  Decimal - 2
```

So I am not seeing what you are seeing when I test it in isolation. So maybe something else is messing it up? Or did I not get the question correctly?

**UPDATE:**

When I run the same tests in the emulator (Android Test) running SDK 24 I get the same results as you did:

```
expected:<2> but was:<0>
expected:<... ( IDR )  Decimal - [2] > but was:<... ( IDR )  Decimal - [0] >
```

Same result on an actual Galaxy S7 ... seems like there is something there ...

Comment: Hey @Kaamel, Have you tested with an android app? or instrumentation test with an app? if so, could you please update it with the Android SDK version and the device/emulator version details as well. For me, I get `0` with Pixel C emulator, Samsung Tab A, and HTC One

Comment: Good point. I actually only unit tested it (no emulator). I will update my response story when I get a chance to Android Test it in the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Google seems to have fixed this on android 10, either knowingly or unknowingly. 
So, on android 10, Currency's  `defaultFractionDigits` method will return `2` for `IDR`, but on android 9 or below, it will keep returning `0`.

Becuase of this, the whole functioning of how we format `IDR` on `UI` broke, and we had to handle it on client itself    :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just misusing `String.format()` in the first example and being burned by a failure of Android to autobox properly.

You have :

```
Log.d("TEST",String.format(locale, "Currency - %s ( %s )  Decimal - %s ",
    currency.getSymbol(locale),
    currency.getSymbol(),
    currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()));
```

Notice that the 3rd replacement parameter in the format is `%s`.  In the code, you call `currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()` to fill that value.   That method returns an `int`  I am not running an android app at the moment, so I can't say for certain how format will respond but generally it may not like being handed an Integer.  `%d` would be a more appropriate parameter in your `String.format()` call.

However, when I run it in a straight Java 8 environment (just cramming into a JUnit test for convenience), it happily reports back "2".

```
@Test
public void tests() {
    Locale   locale   = new Locale("in", "ID");
    Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(locale);
    System.out.println(String.format(locale, "Currency - %s ( %s )  Decimal - %s ",
                                            currency.getSymbol(locale),
                                            currency.getSymbol(),
                                            currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()));
}
```

Which responded with :

> Currency - Rp ( IDR )  Decimal - 2

It seems likely that the `int` returned by `currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()` was autoboxed to an Integer, which was happy to have `.toString()` called on it.

## In conclusion

I do not believe that there is a fundamental difference in the actual response from Currency, but rather the way you printed it and a quirk of the environment.

I suggest at the very least trying `%d` as shown below :

```
Log.d("TEST",String.format(locale, "Currency - %s ( %s )  Decimal - %d ",
    currency.getSymbol(locale),
    currency.getSymbol(),
    currency.getDefaultFractionDigits()));
```

Comment: It's not a formatting issue, `assertEquals(0, currency.getDefaultFractionDigits());` is passing in android.
the issue is I get this as `2` in other jre, where as `0` in android

Comment: @Let'sRefactor I can't imagine why you would downvote me.  Nothing I wrote was wrong and your testing the value specifically in android via the assert is new information you have just provided here.   Your data does indeed suggest a deeper problem in android, but as you have chosen not to provide any version specifics, that was not a viable path to examine from my perspective.

Comment: I believe I have provided enough information in the question. The code is given for describing the issue, where I clearly mentioned that it happens in Android. 
  Your answer, unfortunately, was suggesting it as a `String.format()` issue, which clearly is not. Java will never turn an `int` with value `2` to `0` just because one used `%s` in a `String.format()`
 So, I'm sorry, this answer is not acceptable.

Comment: FWIW.. there is a difference between not the answer you are looking for (which is clearly just a bug somewhere) and an answer that is inappropriate or way off target (which is the purpose of downvoting).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int hargarumah = 66000000;
Locale localeID = new Locale("in", "ID");
NumberFormat formatRupiah = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(localeID);
textview.setText(formatRupiah.format((double)hargarumah));
```